# How to give permission to a makefile to copy a folder?

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

Here's the code:

```
    userPath=$(shell $$HOME)

    move:
        #what is the command?
        cp -r Minesweeper $(userPath)/
```

here's the error message

```
/bin/sh: 1: /home/daniel: Permission denied
cp -r Minesweeper /
cp: cannot create directory '/Minesweeper': Permission denied
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'move' failed
make: *** [move] Error 1
```

For sure there's some command that executed in the terminal can give permission to the makefile, but I need a command to be executed in the makefile.

PS: My ubuntu version is ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I'm running the makefile as the user who owns the directory, so I don't know why I'm not allowed to copy the folder. Actually, when I use the command in the terminal, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Makefile` itself doesn't have or lack permissions. The error message says that *the user who ran this `Makefile`* does not have the required privileges. But this isn't really about permissions; you'll notice that the error says you can't write to the root directory, which of course you neither want nor need (nor should you be allowed to even if you thought you wanted to).

The first error message is because `$(shell $$HOME)` is not a valid command. A valid command would look like `$(shell echo "$$HOME")`; but really, this is completely unnecessary.

The second error is because the first assignment returned an empty variable, because of the first error.

The reason there's no need for a `$(shell ...)` here is that the shell which runs the command is perfectly capable of expanding `$$HOME` by itself. In fact, so can `make` too (though then the syntax is `${HOME}` plain and simple).

```
move:
        cp -r Minesweeper ${HOME}/
```